# ¿Cómo puedo simplificar estas consultas basadas en otra fila de la misma tabla? UPDATE sin nombrar todas las columnas pero excluyendo algunas

Tags: mysql

Estoy trabajando en un sistema que maneja tablas con varias columnas que tienen valores muy similares.

Digamos que mi tabla tiene una columna `semana` que es clave para este asunto. Muchas columnas de la tabla usan los mismos valores, los cuales cambian cada 4 semanas.

Por poner un ejemplo: ya tengo llena toda la fila de la columna `17`, han pasado 4 semanas y me encuentro en la semana `21`. Lo que yo quiero hacer es llenar todas las columnas de la fila correspondiente a la semana `21` usando los datos de la fila correspondiente a la semana `17`.

Las consultas que estoy usando son estas, el `id_celebracion` igual a `253` correspondería a la semana `17` antes mencionada, mientras que el `id_celebracion` `277` sería el de la semana `21`:

```
UPDATE liturgia t2, 
    (SELECT * FROM liturgia WHERE id_celebracion = 253) t1
SET 
    t2.ol_meta = t1.ol_meta,
    t2.ol_antifona = t1.ol_antifona,
    t2.ol_himno = t1.ol_himno,
    t2.ol_salmos = t1.ol_salmos,
    t2.ol_responsorio = t1.ol_responsorio,
    t2.ol_biblica = t1. ol_biblica,
    t2.ol_patristica = t1.ol_patristica,
    t2.ol_oracion = t1.ol_oracion
WHERE t2.id_celebracion = 277;

UPDATE liturgia t2, 
    (SELECT * FROM liturgia WHERE id_celebracion = 253) t1
SET 
    t2.la_meta = t1.la_meta,
    t2.la_himno = t1.la_himno,
    t2.la_salmos = t1.la_salmos,
    t2.la_biblica = t1.la_biblica,
    t2.la_benedictus = t1.la_benedictus,
    t2.la_preces = t1.la_preces,
    t2.la_oracion = t1.la_oracion
WHERE t2.id_celebracion = 277;

UPDATE liturgia t2, 
    (SELECT * FROM liturgia WHERE id_celebracion = 253) t1
SET 
    t2.hi_meta = t1.hi_meta,
    t2.te_himno = t1.te_himno,
    t2.te_salmos = t1.te_salmos,
    t2.te_biblica = t1.te_biblica,
    t2.te_oracion = t1.te_oracion
WHERE t2.id_celebracion = 277;

UPDATE liturgia t2, 
    (SELECT * FROM liturgia WHERE id_celebracion = 253) t1
SET 
    t2.se_himno = t1.se_himno,
    t2.se_salmos = t1.se_salmos,
    t2.se_biblica = t1.se_biblica,
    t2.se_oracion = t1.se_oracion
WHERE t2.id_celebracion = 277;

UPDATE liturgia t2, 
    (SELECT * FROM liturgia WHERE id_celebracion = 253) t1
SET 
    t2.no_himno = t1.no_himno,
    t2.no_salmos = t1.no_salmos,
    t2.no_biblica = t1.no_biblica,
    t2.no_oracion = t1.no_oracion
WHERE t2.id_celebracion = 277;


UPDATE liturgia t2, 
    (SELECT * FROM liturgia WHERE id_celebracion = 253) t1
SET 
    t2.vi_meta = t1.vi_meta,
    t2.vi_himno = t1.vi_himno,
    t2.vi_salmos = t1.vi_salmos,
    t2.vi_biblica = t1.vi_biblica,
    t2.vi_magnificat = t1.vi_magnificat,
    t2.vi_preces = t1.vi_preces,
    t2.vi_oracion = t1.vi_oracion
WHERE t2.id_celebracion = 277;


UPDATE liturgia t2, 
    (SELECT * FROM liturgia WHERE id_celebracion = 253) t1
SET 
    t2.co_meta = t1.co_meta,
    t2.co_kyrie = t1.co_kyrie,
    t2.co_himno = t1.co_himno,
    t2.co_salmos = t1.co_salmos,
    t2.co_biblica = t1.co_biblica,
    t2.co_oracion = t1.co_oracion,
    t2.co_virgen = t1.co_virgen
WHERE t2.id_celebracion = 277;
```

Lo que yo quisiera es hacer una consulta simple que me copie los valores de la semana 17 en la semana 21, **pero hay valores que no me interesa copiar**. Básicamente las únicas columnas que quiero actualizar son las que empiezan con `ol, la, te, se, no, vi, co` ... en el grupo de columnas que empiezan por `te` hay una que rompe ese esquema, porque empieza por `hi`, eso no puedo cambiarlo, debe ser así.

Mi pregunta entonces es ¿cómo simplificar esta consulta de actualización, tomando en cuenta que hay columnas que deben quedar fuera, o sea, que no deben ser actualizadas? En otra palabras, quisiera hacer un `UPDATE` sin tener que nombrar todas las columnas.

Comment: El problema lo vas a tener siempre en la parte en la que asocias cada columna con su valor ya que hay que escribirlo sí o sí. Creo que la mejor opción es hacerlo con código, bien en una aplicación, bien con un procedimiento o función de SQL

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear un procedure que genere dinámicamente la consulta y luego la ejecute (ejemplo de como ejecutar un query desde un varchar);

```
PREPARE stmt3 FROM 'select NOW()';
EXECUTE  stmt3;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
```

Ahora, los parámetros que uses podría ser el listado de campos separados por ',' (Con alguna function podrías manejar el SPLIT y luego utilizar un cursor/ciclo para la asignación de campos), los nombres de las tablas y los id's de los where.